# How to delete a folder from hard drive via xubuntu on usb?

Tags: usb, xubuntu, hard-drive, directory, delete

I'm using http://xubuntu.org/ 12.10 on my memorystick, and i need to delete a folder from my C drive in my computer. 
The folder is in a simple place: C/WINDOWS/program files/"folder name". How can i delete this folder via terminal or something. That folder is the reason i cant mount the rest of C drive..
Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand the last phrase of your question. "That folder is the reason i cant mount the rest of C drive." What is the error ? Did you try to mount it from terminal ? `sudo mount /dev/sd? /mnt` Where "?" the number of partition with Windows listed under `sudo fdisk -l`

Comment: Yea i know all this mountig stuff, but when i try to mount my drive, it stops at that specific folder cause there's something thats stopping ubuntu mounting. Thata why i want to delete it cause it stops the mounting..

Comment: Try to mount it via terminal and give the error back here. Edit your question. If you cannot mount the drive then you have no access to it equals to you cannot delete anything.

Comment: I can mount -.- but how do i delete a file/folder from THE COMPUTERS HARD DRIVE when the xubuntu is on USB? So, if uknow how to do it,post the commands to do it :) thanks

Answer (score 0):

**If you can mount your drive successfully without errors**

Boot from Xubuntu LiveUSB and open a terminal. Then give this command

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

you will see a list with all the partitions - drives of your PC.

Focus on the partition you want to mount.. We assume is /dev/sda2

and then give this command

```
sudo mount /dev/sda2 /mnt
```

Now you have access to this partition and you can delete anything.

Then open nautilus file manager as root and point to this /mnt folder where the partition is mounted

```
gksudo nautilus /mnt
```

search - find - delete.